# Ansible updating nested list

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am working on ansible task with will update a nested list in a list.

Input:

```
- name: test array of objects
  set_fact:
    list: 
       - name: x1
         surname: y1
         childrens: 
            - children1
            - children2
       - name: x2
         surname: y2
         childrens: 
            - children3
            - children4
```

For example, I want *to add new children to* **/** *remove existing children from*  the object with params

```
name: x1
surname: y1
```

Example output (added children):

```
- name: test array of objects
  set_fact:
    list: 
       - name: x1
         surname: y1
         childrens: 
            - children1
            - children2
            - children3
       - name: x2
         surname: y2
         childrens: 
            - children3
            - children4
```

The task will process 1000+ records and should do it efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested variables in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043746/how-to-update-nested-variables-in-ansible)

Comment: Hi Daniel Kruk welcome to SO. You will want to make use of [the search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+update+nested) here because the number of novel problems in ansible is actually pretty small

Comment: already reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347555/ansible-combine-three-lists-of-dictionaries

Comment: @Mirco, how long did it take to loop and concatenate 1000 items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index. For example *fullname*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list: "{{ _list|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        _list: |
          {% for i in range(3) %}
          - name: x{{ i }}
            surname: y{{ i }}
            fullname: x{{ i }}_y{{ i }}
            index: {{ i }}
            childrens:
              - children1
              - children2
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  list:
    - childrens: [children1, children2]
      fullname: x0_y0
      index: 0
      name: x0
      surname: y0
    - childrens: [children1, children2]
      fullname: x1_y1
      index: 1
      name: x1
      surname: y1
    - childrens: [children1, children2]
      fullname: x2_y2
      index: 2
      name: x2
      surname: y2
```

Then convert the list to a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dict: "{{ list|items2dict(key_name='fullname', value_name='childrens') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dict:
    x0_y0: [children1, children2]
    x1_y1: [children1, children2]
    x2_y2: [children1, children2]
```

Update the items of the dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dict: "{{ dict|combine({item.fullname: _children}) }}"
      loop:
        - {fullname: x1_y1, add: [children3]}
      vars:
        _children: "{{ dict[item.fullname] + item.add }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dict:
    x0_y0: [children1, children2]
    x1_y1: [children1, children2, children3]
    x2_y2: [children1, children2]
```

Restore the list from the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ dict|dict2items(key_name='fullname', value_name='childrens') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list2:
    - childrens: [children1, children2]
      fullname: x0_y0
    - childrens: [children1, children2, children3]
      fullname: x1_y1
    - childrens: [children1, children2]
      fullname: x2_y2
```

---

This way, it takes only a couple of seconds to create 1000 items and update a few of them. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list: "{{ _list|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        _list: |
          {% for i in range(1000) %}
      ...

    - set_fact:
        dict: "{{ dict|combine({item.fullname: _children}) }}"
      loop:
        - {fullname: x101_y101, add: [children3]}
        - {fullname: x301_y301, add: [children3]}
        - {fullname: x501_y501, add: [children3]}
      ...

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ list2.100 }}
          {{ list2.101 }}
          {{ list2.102 }}
          {{ list2|length }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    {'fullname': 'x100_y100', 'childrens': ['children1', 'children2']}
    {'fullname': 'x101_y101', 'childrens': ['children1', 'children2', 'children3']}
    {'fullname': 'x102_y102', 'childrens': ['children1', 'children2']}
    1000
```

---

Use [lists_mergeby](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html) to merge all items, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ list|
                   community.general.lists_mergeby(list2, 'fullname')|
                   sort(attribute='index') }}"
```